# How to add a path to the Template Loader depending of the current class based generic view's model in Django

Tags: django-templates, django-class-based-views

I am using the [include](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#include) template tag inside a template of a class based generic view and I  need to append a custom path created with the current model system name to the list of templates that Django is going to check looking for the included template.

I am trying to create a custom template loader, but it needs to access to the view, the request or the context in order to get the model, and I haven't found the way of reach this.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you might find [Inclusion tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags) useful -- just set the decorator's `takes_context` parameter to `True`.

Comment: Thanks! But this solution only works for custom inclusion tags. I would like to use the same custom template loader in both cases: inclusion tags and template views. Also I would like to avoid custom inclusion tags.